# PL/SQL - Loop insert and select

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, insert

I want a reusable script that can be configured by swapping out variable values. I am hoping to be able to loop over a collection of `tag_ids` and insert a row for each tag. Also I want to have a check either side of the insert for visual verification before committing.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
set verify off;
set serveroutput on;

define uname = 'foobar'
define f_name = 'foo'
define l_name = 'bar'

declare
 type numListType is table of number;
 numList numListType;

begin
numList := numListType(432,433,434,435);

for i in numList.FIRST..numList.LAST loop
    dbms_output.put_line('EXPECTING 0');
    select count(*)
    from security_tag_tbl
    where tag_id = numList(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('INSERTING ROW');
    insert into security_tag_tbl (id, username, first_name, last_name, tag_id)
    values (security_tag_tbl_seq.nextval, '&uname', '&f_name', '&l_name', numList(i));

    dbms_output.put_line('EXPECTING 1');
    select count(*)
    from security_tag_tbl
    where tag_id = numList(i);
end loop;
end;
/

set serveroutput off;
set verify on;
```

Issues with this sample:

- This sample returns errors around the select query.
- When I remove the select statements the sample code returns errors with indexes in 'numList'.

Any suggestions about the correct way to approach this scenario?

Comment: And what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Sorry good point I've added details now. Thanks @BobJarvis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all, the above code contains a few problems. You can't use selects in PL/SQL without storing them in a variable with the INTO keyword.

To reproduce your problem, I used these script to create the table and sequence:

```
create table security_tag_tbl (id number, username varchar2(200), first_name varchar2(200), last_name varchar2(200), tag_id number);

create sequence security_tag_tbl_seq;
```

I then modified your code into this:

```
set verify off;
set serveroutput on;

define uname = 'foobar'
define f_name = 'foo'
define l_name = 'bar'

declare
 type numListType is table of number;
 numList numListType;

 firstcount number;
 secondcount number;

begin
numList := numListType(432,433,434,435);

for i in numList.FIRST..numList.LAST loop
    dbms_output.put_line('EXPECTING 0');
    select count(*)
    into firstcount
    from security_tag_tbl
    where tag_id = numList(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('GOT ' || firstcount);


    dbms_output.put_line('INSERTING ROW');
    insert into security_tag_tbl (id, username, first_name, last_name, tag_id)
    values (security_tag_tbl_seq.nextval, '&uname', '&f_name', '&l_name', numList(i));

    dbms_output.put_line('EXPECTING 1');
    select count(*)
    into secondcount
    from security_tag_tbl
    where tag_id = numList(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('GOT ' || secondcount);

end loop;
end;
/

set serveroutput off;
set verify on;
```

You will now get visual feedback about what's happening. Next question is, what to do when you don't get the desired result? You could go for a construction like this where you commit or rollback the transaction based on the results of those counts:

```
set verify off;
set serveroutput on;

define uname = 'foobar'
define f_name = 'foo'
define l_name = 'bar'

declare
 type numListType is table of number;
 numList numListType;

 firstcount number;
 secondcount number;
 errorocured boolean := false;

begin
numList := numListType(432,433,434,435);

for i in numList.FIRST..numList.LAST loop
    dbms_output.put_line('EXPECTING 0');
    select count(*)
    into firstcount
    from security_tag_tbl
    where tag_id = numList(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('GOT ' || firstcount);
    if (firstcount != 0) then
      errorocured := true;
    end if;


    dbms_output.put_line('INSERTING ROW');
    insert into security_tag_tbl (id, username, first_name, last_name, tag_id)
    values (security_tag_tbl_seq.nextval, '&uname', '&f_name', '&l_name', numList(i));

    dbms_output.put_line('EXPECTING 1');
    select count(*)
    into secondcount
    from security_tag_tbl
    where tag_id = numList(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('GOT ' || secondcount);

    if (secondcount != 1) then
      errorocured := true;
    end if;


end loop;


if errorocured = true  then
  dbms_output.put_line('Something wend wrong, rolling back batch');
  rollback;
else
  dbms_output.put_line('Everything ok, committing batch');
  commit;
end if;

end;
/

set serveroutput off;
set verify on;
```

You might also want to look into bulk operations if you're going to use this code for larger numbers or records. Good documentation about it can be found here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i.php